# Responsive Resizing Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, autoresize

I have a map set up on my site that isn't resizing dependant on screen resolution. I'm totally new to web design and need to know how to get this thing resizing. Thank guys.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div style="overflow:hidden;height:300px;width:380px;">
<div id="gmap_canvas" style="height:300px;width:380px;"></div>

<style>
#gmap_canvas img{
max-width:none!important;
background:none!important
}
</style>

<a class="google-map-code" href="http://www.mapsembed.com/baur/" id="get-map-data">mapsembed.com</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function init_map(){
  var myOptions={
    zoom:16,
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.4105461,-3.4874177),
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"),myOptions);
  marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    map:map,
    position:new google.maps.LatLng(51.4084782,-3.4836197)
  });
  infowindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<b>Nina Davies Opticians</b><br/>6 Barons Close House<br/>Llantwit Major | CF62 4NR"
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"click",function(){
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',init_map);

</script>
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly. You're asking real humans for help, not text-parsing robots.

Also, please be more specific about what you've tried and why it's not working.

Comment: Sorry buddy. New to this, but is it really that hard to copy/paste it into Notepad?

Comment: No, but it's kind of a waste of everyone's time when you expect busy people who are still willing to read and answer your question to accommodate. Proper formatting is so easy, it's not unreasonable to expect it. If you're asking for help, try to make it easy for people to help you. Please don't take it personally; this site is about teaching people, and I'm trying to teach you how to write a better question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the width of gmap_canvas to 100%;

CSS:

```
#gmap_canvas { width:100%; height:100%; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="gmap_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Figured it out myself in the end but this is essentially what I did - thank you!